# Load multiple componant on the same page Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, fragment, components, anchor

I'm working on an angular 2 application, to keep the explication short, I have a navbar on the left, and on the rest of the page, and I will display my content.

Those content will be blocks, as in the attached image, the navbar contains 4 actions (Form, test1, details ...)

The content in the middle will display everything, but when I click on form, form will be shown in the middle, when i click on Details, the details block will be shown in the middle.

The user can scroll down and up to see the blocks.

I saw that in Angular 2 we can user Fragment to precise anchor and what blocks we want to show, but the problem is that there is a bug on the fragment functionality.

At the moment, I have a router-outlet that changes the view depending on the url in the routerLink on each button of the navbar. Should I keep using it if i want to display all the blocks/components on the same page?

Thanks for your help,

[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0acO.png)

Answer (score 0):

So in essence, you want a multitude of components, with a menu that doesn't really navigate, but more so has toggle buttons that either display or hide content? What should a page refresh do? Does it matter if you see the same components then? If so, you either have to store state in local storage / session storage / using ngrx... or you have to add the displayed items to the route and resolve those.

Anyhow, in the end you want one component which decides what is displayed, and all the blocks in their own components with their own selectors which you show / hide using *ngIf.

Your html would basically look like this:

```
<my-menu></my-menu>
<my-form *ngIf="showMenu"></my-form>
<my-test1 *ngIf="showTest1"></my-test1>
```

Comment: Actually what i have now, is the navbar on the left, and when i click on contact, the contact component is displayed in the middle, same for other actions.

And what I’m trying to do now, is to have all the component on the same page, and I click on the buttons (navbar) or scroll down/up to see the component I want.

Comment: Ah wait, you want to show them all at all times, and basically have the nav bars just do scrolling? But want to scroll there too when refreshing the page? Still, I'd use the router then to decide which component you want to scroll too on page init.

Comment: Looking at the image i attached in the first comment, you will see a form block in the middle, when i scroll down,  i'll see test block, and the test button in the sidenav will be active (change color)